# How can I check the iframe on my website is secure or not?

Tags: security, iframe

My website has an iframe used for loading my client's websites (only 5).How can I make sure the iframe is secure? Also by editing `iframe src` It allows to load any other websites.How can I prevent it?

Comment: What do you mean by “secure”? Are you talking about HTTPS? Surely if it's your website you have full control over the `iframe src`? The client sites in the frames can be navigated through clicking links in them... what would you prefer happen instead?

Comment: Now editing iframe src allows to load any arbitrary web site inside my site.I'm little worried If someone loads any malicious website inside it,will it harm my site?

Comment: How would anyone other than yourself manage to edit your parent page? In general the DOM of the parent is safe from access from the child page due to the Same Origin Policy. Child frames do have the ability to navigate the parent window, or any of the other frames, but it's not clear that this would have any effect on your model.

Comment: I mean editing the iframe src from web browser `(Like Chrome->Inspect element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean editing the iframe src from web browser (Like Chrome->Inspect element)

You cannot possibly prevent the user from changing anything and everything in the page they are viewing in their browser.

To inject a malicious website, a user would have to deliberately attack themselves. This does not constitute a threat.

Comment: I think it is not clear to the asker that modifying html within his browswer affects only him. It's like drawing mustaches in a newspaper, it only affects the person with that copy of the newspaper, not everyone with that issue.